# Preferred Network Type Settings

Tags: mobile-network, miui, xiaomi-pocophone-f1

I am on Miui and the default setting for the Preferred Network Type doesn't want to save. I want to change it but when ever I close it it won't save. Anyone knows how to fix it?

Comment: For 4G devices, default will be 4G. If you need 3G, just select it, device will save it, and switches to 3G. I don't know why it's not saving settings. Check whether you've applied right ALN4.

Comment: What is ALN4? Also by default it keeps reverting back to LTE/TD-SCDMA/UMTS when I want to have it on LTE/CDMA/UMTS auto (PRL) which gives me much better coverage and will give me 4g more often for some reason.

Comment: Sorry it was a typing mistake. I mean APN settings for that service provider.

Comment: I have just reset it using a built in feature. I will see if that works.